# VB.NET: Cannot display selected data from access database into datagridview

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, datagridview

I have been trying to display selected data from Access database into datagridview on pressing the button but its not displaying any records neither it is showing any error.

```
Dim third_da As OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
Dim third_ds As New DataSet


Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click


    con.Open()
    Dim cb_two As New OleDb.OleDbCommandBuilder(third_da)

    query_three = "SELECT emp_timing.emp_code, emp_timing.day, emp_timing.travel_time, emp_timing.travel_dest,emp_timing.emp_timein,emp_timing.emp_timeout, emp_timing.emp_hours, emp_timing.emp_mins " & _
        "FROM emp_timing WHERE (((emp_timing.emp_code)=" & empcode & ") AND ((emp_timing.day) Like '??/" & ComboBox1.Text & "/20" & TextBox9.Text & "'))"

    ' "WHERE (((emp_timing.emp_code)=22) AND ((emp_timing.day) Like '??/05/2016'))"

    third_da = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(query_three, con)

    third_da.Fill(third_ds, "ets")


    DataGridView1.DataSource = third_ds.Tables("ets")

    con.Close()
    Dim view As New DataView(third_ds.Tables(0))
    source1.DataSource = view
    DataGridView1.DataSource = view

    DataGridView1.ReadOnly = True
    DataGridView1.CancelEdit()

End Sub
```

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Did you set breakpoints and step through? Also use parameters and turn Option Strict On.

Comment: check if your query get the data ?

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection [check bobby-tables.com for details](http://bobby-tables.com), use Parameterized queries to prevent this. DId you debug and check what exactly is going wrong? Is the database getting connected? Is the SQL getting generated correctly? Is the generated SQL getting executed in Access properly?

Comment: What's the type of `day` field ?

Comment: my query is working perfect in access and it can get the data. @AbdellahOUMGHAR

Comment: I have used parameters while inserting data into database now I want to retrieve data from the database so I have no idea how I am going to apply parameters to it.

Comment: type of `day` is `Date/Time`  @AbdellahOUMGHAR

Comment: please put this line `MessageBox.Show(third_ds.Tables("ets").Rows.Count())` after `third_da.Fill(third_ds, "ets")` to show how many rows are selected in query.

Comment: no I haven't set any breakpoints @zaggler

Comment: it is showing 0 @AbdellahOUMGHAR

Comment: that mean the query get 0 data, it is normal that the data are not displayed

Comment: Even though If I change my WHERE clause to this `"WHERE (((emp_timing.emp_code)=22) AND ((emp_timing.day) Like '??/05/2016'))"`  it still doesn't work.

Comment: but if I run the same query into database it works perfect

Comment: Yes i now, t steel found a solution!

Comment: can you bring back data if you just use the select statement? If so then the problem is in your where statement.

Comment: also I bet the issue is:  ((emp_timing.day) Like '??/" & ComboBox1.Text & "/20" & TextBox9.Text & "' When using ' you need two of them ''

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can change you condition of `emp_timing.day` field in query like this :

```
(Month(emp_timing.day) = & ComboBox1.Text & 
                   and Year(emp_timing.day) = "20" & TextBox9.Text & " )
```

But, I advice you to use the Parameter to avoid SQL injections , like this :

```
query_three = "SELECT emp_timing.emp_code, emp_timing.day, emp_timing.travel_time, emp_timing.travel_dest,emp_timing.emp_timein,emp_timing.emp_timeout, emp_timing.emp_hours, emp_timing.emp_mins " &
"FROM emp_timing WHERE (((emp_timing.emp_code)= @empcode) AND ((emp_timing.day) BETWEEN @startDate AND @endDate ))"

Dim startDate As New DateTime("20" & TextBox9.Text, ComboBox1.Text, 1)
Dim endDate As DateTime = startDate.AddMonths(1).AddDays(-1)

Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand(query_three, con)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@empcode", empcode)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@startDate", startDate.ToString("#yyyy/MM/dd#"))
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@endDate", endDate.ToString("#yyyy/MM/dd#"))
third_da = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(cmd)
```

Comment: Thanks a ton brother it worked finally :) here is the query: 
`"SELECT * FROM emp_timing WHERE (((emp_timing.emp_code)=" & empcode & ") AND (Month(emp_timing.day) =" & ComboBox1.Text & "and Year(emp_timing.day) = 20" & TextBox9.Text & " ))"`

Comment: Can you please explain why you wrote Month in this: `(Month(emp_timing.day)` and year in this: `Year(emp_timing.day)`

Comment: Month to get month and year to get year of date field in database and compare it with value in combobox and textbox, because you want to get all record that have date in month for example 05/2016.

Comment: Brother you are awesome :))

Comment: I am glad to hear it! Thank you too :)